# Generate a HTML table from a given word with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I've been able to fish around for solutions and matched them up for my case, but it seems like I hit a dead end.

**Goal:** Website asks you to type any word in textbox and submit it. On submit it generates a table by using JavaScript, breaking the word to letters and placing them on the table diagonally.

**Current position:** I've managed to successfully post the given word in to JavaScript variable, from where I've been able to break the word to separate characters. I've also generated a HTML table with JavaScript, but how do I get the word in there?

I'm happy with an answer that solves that problem of mine, but bonus points are given if it generates  the table and it's content diagonally like this:

```
[ w ] [ - ] [ - ] [ - ]
[ - ] [ O ] [ - ] [ - ]
[ - ] [ - ] [ R ] [ - ]
[ - ] [ - ] [ - ] [ D ]
```

**Here are my codes:**

```js
function printWord() {
  
  var word = document.getElementById('word').value;

  
  var body=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  var tbl=document.createElement('table');
  tbl.style.width='80%';
  tbl.setAttribute('border','1');
  var tbdy=document.createElement('tbody');
  for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
    var tr=document.createElement('tr');
    for(var j=0;j<2;j++){
      if(i==2 && j==1){
        break
      } else {
        var td=document.createElement('td');
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\u0020'))
        i==1&&j==1?td.setAttribute('rowSpan','2'):null;
        tr.appendChild(td)
      }
    }
    tbdy.appendChild(tr);
  }
  tbl.appendChild(tbdy);
  body.appendChild(tbl)

  
  for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    console.log(word.charAt(i));

  }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Help requested - Forming a table from word</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="table">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Type a word:</b></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="word">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="btn" colspan="2">
                        <button type="button" onclick="printWord();">Submit</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Appreciate any help or tips given!

Comment: Any restrictions on word's length ? Your code is generating 3 rows / 2 columns per submit, what if the word is 10 letters long ? shouldn't the columns equal the word's length ? well at least to lay down the letter diagonally ?

Comment: @AwRak No restrictions on word's lenght, that table generating script might not even be that valid for this situation, but just a scratch from a JS generated table I managed to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution for your issue:

```js
function generateTable() {
  var $c = document.getElementById("container");
  var $table = document.createElement('table');
  var $tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
  var word = document.getElementById('word').value.split("");
  $c.appendChild($table);
  $table.appendChild($tbody);
  for (var i=0, l=word.length; i<l; i++) {
    var $tr = document.createElement('tr');
    $tbody.appendChild($tr);
    for (var j=0, jl=word.length; j<jl; j++) {
      var $td = document.createElement('td');
      $td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i==j ? word[i] : "-"));
      $tr.appendChild($td);
    } 
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="word"></textarea><br>
<button id="generate" onclick="generateTable();">Generate</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Using jQuery isn't an option here, forgot to state that. Surely that would do this task a whole lot easier, but it's the last option if nothing else works. Thanks for your answer however.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go..
I have just updated the logic into your code for Printing the Letters.
Try it.

```js
function printWord() {
  
  var word = document.getElementById('word').value;

  
  var body=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  var tbl=document.createElement('table');
  tbl.style.width='80%';
  tbl.setAttribute('border','1');
  var tbdy=document.createElement('tbody');
  for(var i=0;i<word.length;i++){
    var tr=document.createElement('tr');
    for(var j=0;j<word.length;j++){
     
       var td=document.createElement('td');
      if(j==i){
       td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(word[j]));
      }
       tr.appendChild(td)
      
    }
    tbdy.appendChild(tr);
  }
  tbl.appendChild(tbdy);
  body.appendChild(tbl)

  
  for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    console.log(word.charAt(i));

  }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Help requested - Forming a table from word</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="table">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Type a word:</b></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="word">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="btn" colspan="2">
                        <button type="button" onclick="printWord();">Submit</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is way more logical. However it doesn't accomplish my goal, since it doesn't print anything in to the table, just to console.

Comment: @ProDexorite It is printing to the table as Well.
td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(word[j]));
This line of code do so

Answer (score 0):

**Try this.. it is simple and easy to implement:**
[Demo JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chandansharma/47zd3c7g/)

```
<script>
function printWord() {

    var word = document.getElementById('word').value;
    var tableObj = '<table border="1">';
    for(var i=0; i<word.length; i++) {

        var rowObj = '<tr>';
        for(var j=0; j<word.length; j++) {

            var cellObj = '<td>';
            if(i == j) {
                cellObj += word.charAt(i);
            } else {
                cellObj += '-';
            }
            cellObj += '</td>';
            rowObj += cellObj;
        }
        rowObj += '</tr>';
        tableObj += rowObj;
    }
    jQuery('#dynaTableContainer').empty();
    jQuery('#dynaTableContainer').append(tableObj);
}
</script>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Help requested - Forming a table from word</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="table">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Type a word:</b></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="word">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="btn" colspan="2">
                        <button type="button" onclick="printWord();">Submit</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="dynaTableContainer">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks,

~Chandan

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's a reason to create the elements individually, you could build a string of the HTML like this:

```
function buildTable(word) {
  var s= '<table>';
  word.split('').forEach(function(val, idx) {
    s+= '<tr>'+
        (new Array(idx+2).join('<td>'))+val+
        (new Array(word.length-idx).join('<td>'));
  });
  s+= '</table>';
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML= s;
} //buildTable
```

```js
function buildTable(word) {
  var s= '<table>';
  word.split('').forEach(function(val, idx) {
    s+= '<tr>'+
        (new Array(idx+2).join('<td>'))+val+
        (new Array(word.length-idx).join('<td>'));
  });
  s+= '</table>';
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML= s;
} //buildTable
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
Enter a word:
<input id="word" type="text" onchange="buildTable(this.value)">
<div id="output"></div>
```